# printout( ) TypeError bool

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, win32com

```
import win32com.client

ExObj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
ExObj.Visible = 1
wb = ExObj.Workbooks.Open('')
ws = wb.Worksheets[0]
ws.printout()
```

This opens and sends the excel file to the printer and prints it but then produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:/rmarshall/Work For Staff/ROB/_Python/__Python Projects Code/Time Sheet.py", line 26, in <module>
    ws.printout()
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: If everything works as expected just wrap that in a try except (TypeError) block and ignore it.

Comment: `printout` is a boolean value here, not a method, it appears.

Comment: @IonutHulub: Right, just suppress all the exceptions you don't like. Stick your head in the sand, eh?

Comment: That'll be sufficient here, thanks.

Comment: Did you use *printout()* instead of *Printout()* ?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters If you works for ostriches I don't see why it wouldn't work for me.

Comment: @IonutHulub: What works for ostriches is to [run away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrich#Behaviour_and_ecology), actually. :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have used ***printout()*** instead of ***PrintOut()*** and it is case sensitive.

Comment: Indeed, Python is case sensitive; and there is a [`Worksheet.PrintOut()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.printout.aspx).

Comment: +1 but can you explain why it printed? "opens and sends the excel file to the printer and prints it", how is this possible if the method name was wrong? Good catch!

Comment: It doesn't. He might have just said that by assuming it would.